# How to send Html Input file value as an attachment in email uing c#.net

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio, sharepoint-2013

I have been looking for a solution since few days. I am not a .net programmer but I am trying to help someone out with their code. I need to attach any file uploaded via input type=file from an html form.The Html form looks like the following (I have removed any other tags to keep the code short)

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" > 
        <label for="attachAdd">Attach copies of Identification:</label><span>(REQUIRED)</span>  

        <input type="file" id="attachAdd" name="attachAdd" class="file-upload no-print" size="60" />
    </form>
```

My C# code (.cs) file looks like the following:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Globalization;
    using System.Net.Mail;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Data;

    namespace Corp.SP.NewForms
    {
        public class ProcessForms : ParentForm    
        {
             public ProcessForms(string formHTML, EFormMetaData formMetaData, Page requestPage)
                : base(formHTML, formMetaData, requestPage)
            {
                EFormHTML = formHTML;
                EFormMetaData = formMetaData;
                EFormPage = requestPage;
            }    
        public override string ProcessEmail(EFormMetaData formInfo, Page page)
        {
            string email = base.ProcessEmail(formInfo, page);


            //Process body header
            email = email.Replace("{FORMURL}", new UriBuilder(page.Request.Url) { Port = -1 }.ToString());
            email = email.Replace("{EMAILTOADDRESS}", formInfo.EmailToAddress);
            email = email.Replace("{EMAILSUBJECT}", formInfo.EmailSubject);

        string attachAdd = page.Request.Form["attachAdd"];
        System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment;
        attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(attachAdd); //ERROR
        email.Attachments.Add(attachment);                

           return email;
        }
         public override void SendEmail()
        {
                 base.SendEmail();
         }
  }}
```

I feel as if the code used to add attachments is not correct, but I found it on [this question of Stackoverflow](https://forums.asp.net/post/5017402.aspx).

```
    string attachAdd = page.Request.Form["attachAdd"];
    System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment;
    attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(attachAdd); //ERROR
    email.Attachments.Add(attachment);
```

The code shows error with a red line under **Attachments** *(String does not contain definition for "Attachments" and no extension methods "Attachments" accepting a first argument of type 'String' could be found (are you missing a using directive or or an assembly reference))* in the following line.

email.Attachments.Add(attachment);

Can anyone shed a light as to how I can correct this code. We use SharePoint Eforms.

Comment: `email` is a string, as the error says it has no property `Attachments`. You can't try to add an attachment to a string. You probably want to create an email message and attach to that. See the link you posted yourself for how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

To attach the HttpPostedFile  to the email. You will need to convert it to Stream.

Also in your code 'email' is a string . It doesn't have a property Attachment. It should be type MailMessage.

Try as below

```
HttpPostedFile attachAdd = page.Request.Form["attachAdd"];
var email = new MailMessage();
string strFileName =
        System.IO.Path.GetFileName(attachAdd.PostedFile.FileName);
        Attachment attachFile =
        new Attachment(attachAdd.PostedFile.InputStream, strFileName);
        email.Attachments.Add(attachFile);
```

Comment: Hi, I replaced my code bit with yours and now It says String does not contain definition for "PostedFile" and no extension methods "PostedFile" accepting a first argument of type 'String' could be found (are you missing a using directive or or an assembly reference

Comment: attachAdd is not string its the id of input type file in .aspx page..try page.Request.Form["attachAdd"]

Comment: I added    string strFileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(page.Request.Form["attachAdd"].PostedFile.FileName);
            Attachment attachFile = new Attachment(page.Request.Form["attachAdd"].PostedFile.InputStream, strFileName);
     The error persists in postedFile

Comment: String does not contain definition for "PostedFile" and no extension methods "PostedFile" accepting a first argument of type 'String' could be found (are you missing a using directive or or an assembly reference

Comment: I updated my code now there is a red line under page.Request.Form, "cannot implicitly convert type String to System.web.httppostedfile :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143142/discussion-between-shrilekha-and-sachu).